# Must declare scalar variable - already declared and referenced without issue

Tags: sql-server, variables

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE(
    category_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    category_name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @temp_table 
SELECT DISTINCT category.category_name
FROM category

SELECT *
FROM @temp_table
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(year_total) 'total', cat_a_id 
    FROM fin_transactions
    GROUP BY cat_a_id
) AS table_1
ON table_1.cat_a_id = @temp_table.category_id
```

I get an error for the final line, where I "Must declare the scalar variable "@temp_table"", but weirdly not for any other times I have referenced @temp_table. Also it seems as though I have declared it in line 1

Comment: Why you don't use `Alias` on `@temp_table`?

Comment: Use a table alias. Or change the `ON` condition to `table_1.cat_a_id = [@temp_table].category_id`

Comment: The error is trying to hint at the problem. In *that* position, it's interpreting `@something` as a *scalar* variable name, not a *table* variable.

Comment: Why do you think a table variable is useful here? And why do you use DISTINCT when, based on the name, those rows should be unique within the original (category) table?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Alias' after `FROM @temp_table` and it will work

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE(
    category_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    category_name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @temp_table 
SELECT DISTINCT category.category_name
FROM category

SELECT *
FROM @temp_table t  --here changed
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(year_total) 'total', cat_a_id 
    FROM fin_transactions
    GROUP BY cat_a_id
) AS table_1
ON table_1.cat_a_id = t.category_id --and here changed
```

Comment: @alangap23, please accept my answer if it was helpful.